# Why Django migration alter field (AlterField) that is not touched?

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

When i do migration `python manage.py makemigrations wall`
i see in console that Django (1.8.12) tells me a long list of fields that are touched:

```
Migrations for 'wall':
  0079_auto_20170302_0024.py:
    - Add field periodic_task_interval to userproject
    - Alter field bank_problems on bankireference
    - Alter field bank_problems_category on bankireference
    - Alter field bank_products on bankireference
    - Alter field bank_products_category on bankireference
    - Alter field extr_category on bankireference
    - Alter field extr_words on bankireference
    - Alter field neg_features on bankireference
    - Alter field neutral_features on bankireference
    - Alter field pos_features on bankireference
    - Alter field tonality_category on bankireference
    - Alter field tonality_words on bankireference
    - Alter field bank_problems on fbpagepost
    - Alter field bank_problems_category on fbpagepost
    - Alter field bank_products on fbpagepost
    - Alter field bank_products_category on fbpagepost
    - Alter field extr_category on fbpagepost
```

...... ad so on, near all fileds that is ManyToManyField. I also checked other migrations, looks like random choose of fields, because i see also    `tagulous.models.fields.TagField` 
and even 
`models.TextField`.

**BUT, i am sure a did not changed that fields, even touched them**

This is what in 0079_auto_20170302_0024.py for untouched fields:

```
......
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='userproject',
        name='description',
        field=models.TextField(default='', verbose_name='Description', blank=True, null=True),
    ),
......
```

The only thing i have done is added `- Add field periodic_task_interval to userproject` so other fields - why they appear in migration?
Can this effect a long time doing actual migration because of big database?

Comment: Try running `sqlmigrate` and see what it says. Sometimes I have random migrations generated when I use something like `choices=a_dict.items()` and it returns the choices in a different order than before. Until Python 3.6, the order is undefined so this is expected behavior, I use `OrderedDict` for such things now.

Comment: @Anonymous ok, i have choices, but what about ManyToManyField - there is no any choices

Answer (score 2):

if you have  choices= parametr in field, you should generate it in "stable way" (same order every time), for example with sorted()

```
TYPES = {
    'DISTRICT': 'Округ',
    'AREA': 'Район',
    'STATION': 'Станция метро',
}
type = models.CharField(
    max_length=255,
    choices=sorted(TYPES.items()),
    default='AREA',
)
```